# Sending data from ASP.NET to android

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, sockets

I'm creating a viber-like application, i.e. android users can make instant messages in their android-powered devices. I've created client-to-server webservices using ASP.NET (ASMX service with JSON response) and it works like a charm, but the other side, i.e. server-to-client requests is just a little headache. Of course I can make my application so that there is no need to server-to-cliend requests (sending dummy requests from client to server in short periods) but in this way server will be overloaded specially when number of users increases. I've found some technologies regarding instant messaging, including GCM and XMPP. What are my other options? or let me ask what is my best option? 
Should I use sockets? If so, how can I always have my clients IP (considering that clients are mobile users which may be using WiFi or GPRS/3G/4G internet). I'm thinking of a system in which my clients send their IP each n seconds (n can be around 30), so server always has a (nearly) up-to-date list of client IPs.
Is it possible or even logical to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely consider using GCM [(Google Cloud Messaging for Android)](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

You need to setup a few things in your server to be able to use it to send via GCM.
Its the built-in way to send data from a server to an android device, hope this can help

[Implementing GCM Server](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using the good old strategy of long-polling is always possible, but there are much better ways to do it nowadays. That's perhaps the fastest to implement of the mentioned (not so if you want to implement it correctly and with min amount of load on your server/DB engine). I've seen some projects that start around that architecture with the idea to move to something better in the future .... and the moment to move never comes of course. If you start browsing your Android phone connected to a proxy like Charles you'll see what I mean :)

WebSockets are an option, but I don't see a reason why I'd use them for a Viber-like app, which is event-based (you've received a message) and not "real-time" (monitoring some stock graphics movements for example).

Your best choice here is [a Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)! It's easy to implement it both on your backend and on the client, and it's built specifically with the problematic connectivity in mind (switching between wifi/poor 3g/4g/etc). It has some pretty nice features that other methods don't provide "out of the box" - message resending (the common scenario of a client loosing his connection - GCM it'll send the push notification later, when he comes online), automatic syncing between devices (smartphone, tablet, etc) and others.

Comment: Sorry bit late, but i have exactly the same question. I too feel polling will block resources when traffic increases. Some guys say use Push Notifications? Did you try GCM? what do you feel @Ali_dotNet? what worked best for you? Im basically interested in Asp.Net connecting to my android device, any success/tips?

Comment: Push notifications is exactly the same as GCM :) To be exact, GCM stands for Google Cloud Messaging and basically is the infrastructure you use to implement push notifications. No doubt about this one, definitely go for GCM!